# Какое из выражений построено правильно: «одно за другим» или «одно за одним»?

Tags: фразеология

Какое из выражений построено правильно: «одно за другим» или «одно за одним»? «Одно за одним» мне очень режет слух.

Answer (score 2):

1) Что говорят источники

а) Толковый словарь Ефремовой: **один за другим** **- нареч. разг.** - друг за другом; один за одним.

б) Как правильно один за другим или один за одним?
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
**В значении "поочередно" - один за другим.**

2) Как пишут в Нацкорпусе

Значительно чаще применяется "один за другим" без особой ориентации на смысл или стиль.

3) А нам что делать? Попробуем найти разные смысловые оттенки

Если предметы **однородные, не различаются, образуют вереницу**, то это "один за одним": Проносятся дни, один за одним. Унылые дни тянутся один за одним.

Если предметы разные и нужно показать **их очередность следования** в пространстве или времени, то "один за другим": Начиная с 1860 года, выходят из печати один за другим романы Уилки Коллинза. Вот остановились и стали один за другим спускаться вниз.

Comment: Интересно, получается, что Ефремова правильный оборот объясняет через неправильный )))

Comment: У местоимения "один" несколько значений, в частности:  1) какой-либо предмет из ряда  однородных предметов: одно другому не мешает. 2) тот же самый: одно к одному (о неприятностях, идущих сплошной чередой). Скорее всего, здесь дело не в стиле, а в незначительной разнице в смысловых оттенках, которую пользователи не считают нужным обозначать и выбирают первое значение.

Comment: Да, много есть не свете, друг Горацио. Но я как-то не нахожу в том объяснения, почему Ефремова правильную (якобы) конструкцию объясняет через (якобы) неправильную.  )))).  Vera, мое замечание вполне конкретно, и если уж отвечаете, то и отвечайте конкретно.

Comment: Извините, мне показалось, что вы поймете мою мысль и нет необходимости делать вполне ясный вывод. А вывод такой:  мне тоже непонятно, почему Ефремова считает "друг за другом" разговорным вариантом. А почему мне это непонятно, я уже объяснила. Еще раз сожалею, что  вы меня не поняли, буду в дальнейшем  отвечать "корректно".

Comment: Я не пытался искать мысль, я пытался найти ответ на свой вопрос. Вы его ни тогда, ни сейчас не дали.

Comment: Другой вариант:   Вы ни сначала и не потом его (ответа) не нашли.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, "одно за другим". Правильно режет слух. Не очень понятно, почему у Ефремовой это помечено *разг.* Тогда "одно за одним" должно быть помечено *вдвойне разг.* Почти то же самое, что "взад-назад", такое ведь тоже встречается.

Answer (score 0):

Я дймаю, что оба варианта правильные. Большого смысла в ответе "Справки" я не вижу, ибо что там делает значение "поочередно" вообще непонятно. "Один за одним", один за другим - это не "поочередно", это упорядоченно во времени или пространстве, "поочередно" - в лучшем случае весьма слабый синоним. А если понимать "поочередно" очень широко, то какие еще значения могут быть у "один за другим"?

Нет, я полагаю, что здесь просто дело традиции, "один за другим" на слух воспринимается лучше, так как нет нежелательного здесь рефрена. Но это не значит, что второй вариант неправилен. Причем без всякой видимой разницы в значениях.